# MongoDB How to find which polygon contains a specified Point?

Tags: mongodb, geometry, point, geo

I insert many polygons into MongoDB(2.4.8), and hope find the polygon a specified Point sits in. It seems a common question. But after reading all docs from google, I didn't get the result. So create this question.

e.g.

```
db.addr_poly.insert(
{ loc :
   { type : "Polygon" ,
     coordinates : [ [ [ 0 , 0 ] , [ 3 , 6 ] , [ 6 , 1 ] , [ 0 , 0 ] ] ]
} })
db.addr_poly.insert(
{ loc :
   { type : "Polygon" ,
     coordinates : [ [ [ 0 , 0 ] , [ -3 , -6 ] , [ -6 , -1 ] , [ 0 , 0 ] ] ]
} })
```

Now how to find the polygon which contains Point(1,1)?

Anybody can help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [$geoIntersects operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/). It queries for all shapes which intersect the GeoJSON object you pass. When you pass a point to it, it should return all shapes which include that point. Keep in mind that the $geoIntersects operator only works for 2dsphere indexes, not for 2d indexes.

Comment: It works! I'm sorry I just tried $geoWithin. Philipp, thanks a lot!

Comment: @fanzhou When this answer was correct, please mark it as such by clicking the tick-icon next to it.

Comment: @Philipp can you explane more about the query? i need an example for this query :)

Answer (score 5):

As @philipp said, you should use the $geoIntesects operator. I was having the hardest time trying to figure out the query. I figured I would share what it looks and it might save someone the trouble later.

```
db.addr_poly.find({
    loc:{
        $geoIntersects: {
            $geometry: {
              type: "Point" ,
              coordinates: [1, 1]
            }
         }
     }
});
```

Comment: Could you please give an example how to do this using Mongo Java Driver? or MongoTemplate.  Thanks.

Comment: I am not familiar with the syntax for either. Sorry.